# `attemptRecovery(fromError:optionIndex:)` not found on super of Swift subclass of NSDocument

Tags: objective-c, swift, nsobject, nsdocument

I've an objC NSDocument subclass, which is itself subclassed by a Swift version. The ObjC version calls `BOOL result=[self attemptRecoveryFromError:error optionIndex:recoveryOptionIndex];`, which is implemented by the Swift subclass.

From the Swift subclass, for certain errors, a call is made to super as follows:

```
    guard let (error as NSError).domain == "someDomain" else {
        return super.attemptRecovery(fromError: error, optionIndex: recoveryOptionIndex)
    }
```

This method is not implemented by the ObjC subclass but should be implemented by NSObject, but during runtime I get the following error:

```
-[App.AppDocument attemptRecoveryFromError:optionIndex:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x60000350d340
```

Why does it not find the method? Does it perhaps have something to do with the type of Error not necessarily being a NSError?

Comment: `attemptRecoveryFromError:optionIndex:` is a method of informal protocol [NSErrorRecoveryAttempting](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nserror/nserrorrecoveryattempting?language=objc) and is not implemented by `NSObject`.

Comment: [This page](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/objectivec/nsobject/1416402-attemptrecoveryfromerror?language=objc) suggests otherwise. Did I misunderstood it?

Comment: Yes "Implemented" means it can be implemented. `NSObject` doesn't know how to recover. See [Formal and Informal Protocols](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/General/Conceptual/DevPedia-CocoaCore/Protocol.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008195-CH45-SW2) and [Error Recovery](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ErrorHandlingCocoa/ErrorRespondRecover/ErrorRespondRecover.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001806-CH203-BAJJHBED).

Comment: @Willeke I see it now. If you make it an answer I can mark it as such. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`attemptRecoveryFromError:optionIndex:` is a method of informal protocol `NSErrorRecoveryAttempting` and is not implemented by `NSObject` See [Formal and Informal Protocols](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/General/Conceptual/DevPedia-CocoaCore/Protocol.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008195-CH45-SW2)

> An informal protocol is a category on NSObject, which implicitly makes almost all objects adopters of the protocol. (A category is a language feature that enables you to add methods to a class without subclassing it.) Implementation of the methods in an informal protocol is optional. Before invoking a method, the calling object checks to see whether the target object implements it. Until optional protocol methods were introduced in Objective-C 2.0, informal protocols were essential to the way Foundation and AppKit classes implemented delegation.

More info: [Error Recovery](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ErrorHandlingCocoa/ErrorRespondRecover/ErrorRespondRecover.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001806-CH203-BAJJHBED).